# Finding a homotopy between two counterclockwise circles.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently working on the following question. I am lost and really don't know where to start. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Suppose $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are two counterclockwise circles so that $a$ is inside both of them. Give a homotopy that proves $\gamma_0 \sim_{\mathbb{c}\backslash \{a\}} \gamma_{1}$.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What have you tried? Does the "obvious approach" of drawing lines from $a$ work?

Comment: @Lena Calvin gave essentially the entire solution in his comment, so you are going to need to expound far more if you want help... it's hard to say where your knowledge gap is unless you write more about what in particular you are struggling with

Comment: I guess I don't understand what a formula for this would look like and how to include a in that formula. I understand how to find a homotopy between two circles centered at the origin, but I'm not sure how a being inside each circle and not necessarily the origin affects this.

Comment: I am currently starting with $\gamma_0 = re^{2 \pi it}+w$ and $\gamma_1 = pe^{2 \pi it} +z$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $|a-w|<r$ and $|a-z|<p$.

Comment: I currently have $h(t,s) = [r-s(r-p)]e^{2 \pi it} +w-s(w-z).$ I think this satisfies the conditions for a homotopy I am just not sure if it is never equal to $a$.

Comment: Note: you can address people on here directly by writing ````@theirusername``` so they are notified of your progress.